# How can I send a file by email with PHP Mailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have been trying for some time to make a code in php to send a file from a form.

The form works, it uploads both the information and the file to the server.

I submit the form with AJAX.

Problem:

When I do email tests, I only receive the message... without an attachment, or it doesn't even reach on the Google email. When I remove the line of code for the attachment, I also receive the message on google mail.
In short, the code works perfectly if I remove the line of code for adding the attachment.

Can someone help me?

I am a beginner in PHP.

```
    require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';


    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;


    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);


    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';


    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;


    $mail->Host = Config::SMTP_HOST;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = Config::SMTP_PORT;


    $mail->Username = Config::SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = Config::SMTP_PASSWORD;


    $mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-Version', '1.0');
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    

    $mail->setFrom($customerEmail, $customerName);
    $mail->addAddress($sellerEmail, $sellerName);
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
   
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subjectForSeller;
    $mail->Body = $messageForSeller;

    $mail->send();
```

Comment: Why are you using all these custom headers?

Comment: I'm a beginner... that's how I saw through different tutorials to be able to send an html message and create a visually beautiful message from the tables.

Comment: Check out the [official example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example).

Comment: Even better, check out the [send file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps). As @Olivier said, you don't need to set those headers; PHPMailer takes care of these for you. I suggest you start again with this example, get it working as-is, and only then start to make changes to it. That way you can be sure what it was you did that broke it :). If you're a beginner, it might be a good time to learn about version control too...

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try everything you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this lines:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-Version', '1.0');
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$mail->addCustomHeader('Viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
$mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
```

and Check size (less than 25 meg) and mime type of file (not EXE, APK, etc.) and upload it on your host. Then use path of file on the host and a clean name (just number/alphabets with extension) in $mail->addAttachment.

Comment: *"Code is good and clean."* No, it's not. You can't attach a file if you set the content-type to `text/html`.

Comment: You are right, I edit my answer :)

Comment: @esqew why remove the last line !? I just try to be polite...

Comment: @hanifzekri I removed it because it's fluff unrelated to the core of the question or your answer, and doesn't conform to the overall Q&A structure of Stack Overflow. [Further reading and relevant discussion on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412759/is-it-acceptable-to-put-if-you-have-any-questions-or-something-wasnt-right-jus)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try everything you indicated.

Comment: My pleasure, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, which I verified to be working (sending an E-Mail w/ attachment to my GMail):

```
$subjectForSeller = 'This is the subject';
$messageForSeller = 'Hello <strong>World</strong>';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = Config::SMTP_HOST;
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Port       = Config::SMTP_PORT;

$mail->Username   = Config::SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password   = Config::SMTP_PASSWORD;

$mail->setFrom($customerEmail, $customerName);

$mail->addAddress($sellerEmail, $sellerName);
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
} else {
    $messageForSeller .= ' FILE NOT FOUND!';
}

$mail->isHTML(true);
```

While the line

```
$messageForSeller .= ' FILE NOT FOUND!';
```

is for debugging purposes only, you should **always** use *is_uploaded_file* for verification.

And this is the HTML form I used for testing:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Edit**: I've tried your code snippet as well and it's working just fine, so there might me something wrong with your file or file upload. You may want to add the form, the AJAX call and a link to the test file to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try everything you indicated.